# Issue with setImageWithURLRequest in AFNetworking in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I have written the following function for my iPhone application to load the image from the url.

```
- (void) downloadImage:(UIImageView *) sliderImage fromUrl:(NSString *)url{

    NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];

    [sliderImage setImageWithURLRequest:request placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ImageThumb.png"] success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {
        [sliderImage setImage:image];
    }
                              failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                  NSLog(@"Image fetch error %@",response);
                              }];

}
```

It was worked fine in the development environment. When we switch into the production environment with amazon s3. The same method shows the following error.

```
Image fetch error <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x16750060> { URL: https://xxx.s3.amazonaws.com/images/xxx/17/630/Photo/1447846574_FlwJYa6rpI64w5J.jpg } { status code: 200, headers {
    "Accept-Ranges" = bytes;
    "Content-Length" = 733355;
    "Content-Type" = "image/jpg";
    Date = "Wed, 18 Nov 2015 12:46:07 GMT";
    Etag = "\"e1f9sdw2ad071a3afsf2423b484a\"";
    "Last-Modified" = "Wed, 18 Nov 2015 11:36:15 GMT";
    Server = AmazonS3;
    "x-amz-id-2" = "+o/vxxxxxasdaxasdaxxxxxxsd=";
    "x-amz-request-id" = 0D5E0340BC5BDFF6;
} }
```

I tried the following scenario,

1. Uploaded image in iOS with AFNetworking Library
2. I can see the images in Android device which is uploaded via iOS device.
3. I can also see the images that is uploaded via Android in My iPhone Application.
4. When i try to see the My uploaded image in iOS i'm getting the above error.

Thanks in advance, Can anyone please provide any suggestions to handle the above issue.

code used for uploading

```
  NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer] multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:url parameters:params constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
            [formData appendPartWithFileData:data name:@"media" fileName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@",[self randomStringWithLength:15],extension] mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
        } error:nil];

    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    AFURLSessionManager *manager = appDelegate.urlSessionManager;       
    NSProgress *progress = nil;

    NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask = [manager uploadTaskWithStreamedRequest:request progress:&progress completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, id responseObject, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        } else {

        }
    }];    

    //6.Send request
    [uploadTask resume];
```

Comment: In the `failure` block, what is the `error` you are getting? Please add that too.

Comment: but your code in download image from server not uploading ...

Comment: Thanks for your response @Nishant. I have already provided the failure error. as ( Image fetch error <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x16750060> { URL....)

Comment: Thanks for your response @Anbu.Karthik. I have updated my upload code

Comment: @Prabhu: No you have not. I want this             `NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);` in the download failure block. You are printing the response.